# Kibana 3 documentation

Tags: kibana

I have not been any usual documentation at all. I can't find anything on [Elasticsearch](http://www.elastic.co/guide/).

I have seen a few blog articles and that's about it.

Comment: I do not think there is any docs for Kibana. There is a support page: http://www.elasticsearch.com/support/, but nothing else. You can ask here in SO if you have any doubt :D

Comment: Hi again @lingo_journey, I found this: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/tree/master/docs It could be helpful for you.

Comment: the documentation for kibana 3 is found at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/kibana/3.0/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the documents on GitHub:

http://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/tree/master/docs

Answer (score 18):

The Kibana 3 docs can be found here: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/3.0/index.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition there is a nice open Source project called Stagemonitor. 
Stagemonitor is a Java monitoring agent that integrates Kibana.
http://www.stagemonitor.org/

There is nice quick start demo.
In combination with the Spring Framwork Petclinic you can set up  a Kibana Dashoard, call stacks and create individual Dashboard.
The documentation is good and its gives a nice overview.
https://github.com/stagemonitor/stagemonitor/wiki/Installation