# Kibana/ElasticSearch dashboard json schema definition

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

We've been using Kibana/ElasticSearch to analyze our logs for a bit and I'm trying to understand the dashboard definitions a bit. When I export a dashboard and inspect the resulting file, I can see that it's json.  As such, I can manipulate it by hand and one thing I've found helpful is to add custom attributes for comments to my filters.  e.g.

```
"2": { 
  "_filter_comment": "comment justifying this filter",
  "type": "field",
  "field": "msg",
  "query": "\"something I want to filter\"",
  "mandate": "mustNot",
  "active": true,
  "alias": "",
  "id": 2
},
```

This then allows me to see the comment in Kibana.  Playing with the json, I've been able to learn some more helpful tips, but I'd prefer to go to the "source" (a.k.a. docs) assuming such a thing exists to expedite my understanding.  One specific feature that I'd love to get a better understanding of is how to use regexes in my filters.  Does such a "source" exist, and if so can someone direct me to it?

Answer (score 1):

The only documentation that I found is the one that they have in the folder `docs` in [their Github repo](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/tree/master/docs/kibana). At the moment, I do not think that there is more docs provided by them, as I mention in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21684226/1004046).